# What happened to comments on the blog?

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

The most recent posts on [the SO blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/) all seem to have comments disabled.

Is this deliberate? If so, why? And if so, are you aware that you can still comment on the old posts?

Comment: @ColleenVpartedways the question is not remarking *that* comments are disabled, but inquiring *why*.

Comment: @ColleenVpartedways Blog posts don't solicit discussion; they elicit it. That aside, the standard has always been that you can comment on blog posts at Stack Overflow to discuss it, ask questions about it, or comment on some part of it. This is also an *exceedingly common* paradigm for blog posts and news articles across the web. Considering this, and the fact that the company has made noise about moving more of this content away from Meta posts over to the blog, it is a perfectly reasonable question to pose when a pattern change that stifles community discussion occurs.

Comment: @ColleenVpartedways the question *does* ask literally that.

Comment: Perhaps because they now open Meta posts to ask for feedback explicitly, hence moving the discussion back to MS(E/O).

Comment: @Luuklag Only some have links to a meta post.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just seeing this.

There was a single post that I was asked to disable comments on in order to route everyone to a linked Meta post. But there was a bug that turned off comments for all subsequent blog posts. I was getting lonely over there, and there was no setting visible to me to change it.

But it's fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, can you please mark this as [tag:status-completed], since it turned out to be a bug?

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance I don't think he can, since he is lacking a Diamond, or is the description of "Moderator-only-tag" on the tags page outdated?

Comment: @Luuklag he's marked as "staff", see in his profile as well. While no visible symbol (except in profile), any staff can add mod only tags, and they also get "privileges by demand" beyond it.

Comment: @Ryan, thanks for being with us on Meta. We appreciate it a lot!

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance Done!